# KnockoutJS: multiselect issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, knockout.js, multi-select

I have a very simple case using a multiselect `select` element with KnockoutJS 3.  If you use the `selectedOptions` binding with a multiselect element with IE (any version), the select element always bounces to the bottom-most selected element when selecting a new option.  I've seen many articles that seem somewhat related to this and extremely outdated, but no definitive solution.  Any help appreciated.

Simple example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/unp9j9dc/1

Reproduce by clicking Item 1, holding control, clicking item 20, then going back to item 2.  UI will bounce back to item 20.

In addition, I should mention that while the JSFiddle is using knockout 3.0.0, I am using 3.2.0 locally with the same results.  I'll be trying 3.3.0 shortly.

**UPDATE**: same results with Knockout 3.3.0 also.

Comment: Same issue exists in an [official example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/betterList.html) also.

Comment: [Possibly related bug report](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1354).  If I remove the `selectedOptions` binding from your example, the issue disappears.

Comment: Thanks @JamesThorpe.  Yes, you could also make selectedOptions a non-observable array, which makes it basically one-way binding (from the UI to the model).  That kind of takes away from the power of Knockout though.  I could potentially go down that path, but it would really make things messy.

Comment: Yeah I agree it's not the right way to go - just highlighting it was the same as that bug (bad behaviour in IE when using that binding).  May or may not be related!

Comment: Thanks for your help @JamesThorpe, I ended up changing the code, which I'll send a pull request for soon as I believe it's a perfectly valid fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it.  I am using subscriptions and two way binding pretty extensively and all of that seems to still work properly.

Basically, the KO infrastructure just goes through and syncs up the UI with the updated model binding on a UI or model update.  Thus, it is setting every options' `selected` property on a UI update, and when it "re-selects" the last one, IE decides to scroll it into view.

I took the debug version of Knockout 3.2.0 and edited lines 305-310 to NOT attempt to update the options' selected property if it is already equal to whatever is being set.  I plan to submit a pull request for this when I get time, but here it is if anyone else runs into this.

**UPDATE**:
Thanks again, to @JamesThorpe, [here is the source I edited.](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/1e5e890faeca763021cf19e22c3f953a2e74fb86/src/utils.js#L286-L292)

```
        setOptionNodeSelectionState: function (optionNode, isSelected) {
            // IE6 sometimes throws "unknown error" if you try to write to .selected directly, whereas Firefox struggles with setAttribute. Pick one based on browser.
            if (ieVersion < 7)
                optionNode.setAttribute("selected", isSelected);
            else if (optionNode.selected != isSelected)
                optionNode.selected = isSelected;
        },
```

Comment: To complete this answer, could you link to [the source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/1e5e890faeca763021cf19e22c3f953a2e74fb86/src/utils.js#L286-L292) of what you've edited, so it's easy to compare what's been changed?

Comment: There's a typo in the fix (at least as you've put it on here) - it should be `optionNode.selected = isSelected`

Comment: Thanks again @JamesThorpe, I updated the answer to include all that.

Comment: What should i do, if i DO NEED to select all elements in SELECT, but to PREVENT scrolling to last element in IE?